Half of a string using regex
I'm looking to capture groups of equal size, but there's more than just one unary character in my string (eg the usual (.*)\1 trick doesn't work because the second half is different from the first)
I have a loop that just tries ^(.{1})(.{1})$ with every number, but that's very cumbersome in sed, and I feel like there should be a more elegant way. This specific time my regex flavor is sed EREs, but I've encountered this problem before when working with other flavors as well so if you have an answer in a different flavor I would appreciate that as well. This comment shows that it's at least possible with some flavors: ^(?:.(?=.*?((?(1).\1|.)$)))+\K\1
--
The comments asked for explicit examples, so here are some examples of strings getting split in half...
"Input"    -> "Captured" "Groups"
"1234"     -> "12" "34"
"aa"       -> "a" "a"
"examples" -> "exam" "ples"
"101010"   -> "101" "010"
"1@ #t4r/" -> "1@ #" "t4r/"

"a b c    defgh" -> "a b c  " "  defgh"
"abc    def"     ->   "abc  " "  def"
"abcd  e  f"     ->   "abcd " " e  f"

if you need more examples, you can just click on that first link, put your example in the input box, and click the 'run' button.

Also see this question... With one capture group for just end e.g. ^(?:.(?=.*?(.\1?$)))+?.?\1$|. or two capture groups for start and end: ^((?:.(?=.*?(.\2?$)))+?).?\2$|. (not sure how well this suits your needs). I think it will work where forward references are supported, such as PCRE, Java, .NET, maybe Python.

The desire to do this with a regex seems absurd. What practical purpose does this have which isn't better served by something like awk '{ print(substr($0, 1, length($0)/2)) }' or etc?

deleted several comments from an argument; in case you were wondering, arbitrary squarification is the use case

This seems like an unusual use for sed and regexp. You're not matching any kind of pattern, why use a regexp? Use a language where you can get the length of the input, divide by 2, and then get substrings by length.

Do you really have this input format with leading and trailing double quotes? And do you expect the exact output format you show ("input" -> "left" "right")? Or is this just a way to present inputs/outputs in a single code block? If the latter I suggest that you edit your question and show in 2 separate code blocks your exact input and the exact output you expect.

@RenaudPacalet that's just a way to present inputs/outputs in a single code block; but rather than an exact input and output I'm more looking for things matching the same general idea. basically 'sed or regex strategies that split things in half' is all that I'm looking for. maybe even specifying 'half' rather than 'dividing equally' was too specific for what I'm asking, as other arbitrary fractions are also useful, but over here on stack overflow y'all love your specificity.

@guest4308 I see. The problem is that people trying to help you cannot really test their proposals without a well defined specification. And SO is not really about "general ideas" (many questions are closed because they are too vague or because they ask for recommendations, or are considered as opinion-based). SO is about programming issues. It would be much better if you provided a clear specification and, based on the answers you will get, elaborate yourself about the "general ideas" they suggest. The help center explains all this better than I could.

@guest4308 There is another good reason for providing accurate input/output specifications, and your question is a nice example of this: most answers you will get will spend a fair amount of technicality to keep the original string, add the -> separator, handle the double-quotes, etc. They will probably be uselessly complicated for your needs and you will have more difficulties to understand them than with a simpler specification.

@RenaudPacalet the answers I have gotten here are very helpful to me though. for example, that ~250 char script earlier is now only 100 chars using strategies from the answers here. it's not like I'm just going to directly run code from internet strangers; what I'm looking for is new ways to look at things and alternate strategies; a fresh pair of eyes.

@RenaudPacalet I will clarify though, this question is in fact about splitting strings in half and not about squarifying them; that's just one application that I am using it for ^^

Please post a [mcve] with concise, testable, sample input and expected output as 2 separate blocks, 1 input and the other output, that we can simply copy paste to test a potential solution with. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more people will have the time to try to help you. See [ask] and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples. Add an example where the input isn't an even number of characters, e.g. abc, and don't expect people to click on any links to be able to figure out your needs as that's again unnecessary effort and may be blocked.

Unless it is an exercise, using sed and regular expressions for this is probably uselessly complicated. With any POSIX (2024) awk you can split a string in 2 halves (or in more pieces) based on its length:
awk '{n=int(length/2); print $0 " -> " substr($0,1,n) "\" \"" substr($0,n+1)}' file

If your intent is string "squarification", as your comments suggest, awk (or perl, python, ...) would also be more appropriate than sed and regular expressions:
awk '{n=int(sqrt(length)); if(n*n != length) exit(1)
for(i=0; i<n; i++) print substr($0,n*i+1,n)}' file

But if you really want to split lines in half with sed you could:

first copy the input string in the hold space (h) for later reuse,
enclose the input string in newline characters (s/.*/\n&\n/),
iteratively move the newline characters until they reach the middle (:a;s/\n(.)(.*)(.)(\n)/\1\4\2\4\3/;ta),
append a newline character and the hold space to the pattern space (G),
swap them and replace the newline separator with -> (s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 -> \1/),
and post-process to obtain your expected output format (s/\n(.)?\n/\1" "/).

With GNU sed:
sed -E 'h;s/.*/\n&\n/;:a;s/\n(.)(.*)(.)\n/\1\n\2\n\3/;ta;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 -> \1/;s/\n(.)?\n/\1" "/' file

With any POSIX (2024) sed:
sed -E 'h;s/.*/\n&\n/;:a
s/\n(.)(.*)(.)(\n)/\1\4\2\4\3/;ta
G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 -> \1/;s/\n(.)?\n/\1" "/' file

In case what you really want is just cut a single string in halves and print in two separate lines we can simplify. With GNU sed:
sed -E 's/.*/\n&\n/;:a;s/\n(.)(.*)(.)\n/\1\n\2\n\3/;ta;s/\n(.)?\n/\1\n/' <<< 'my nice string'
my nice
 string

With any POSIX (2024) sed:
sed -E 's/.*/\n&\n/;:a
s/\n(.)(.*)(.)(\n)/\1\4\2\4\3/;ta
s/\n(.)?(\n)/\1\2/' <<< 'my nice string'
my nice
 string

(if the length of the input string is odd the first line will have one more character than the second).

that tio.com link by the OP isn't "string squaring". Although the concept doesn't have a formal term, I'd call it "string square-rooting" instead. If you're "integer squaring" (for n >= 2), the result must be larger than the input. Similarly, "string squaring" (for str-length >= 2) should result in a longer string.

The extra copies of \n doesn't count as making it "longer string" since those are merely arbitrary delineators inserted for formatting purposes. An example of "string squaring" would be taking a string 16-characters long, run gsub(/./, str, str) one single time, to yield an output that is 256-characters long, made up of 16 consecutive copies of the input string.

"Squaring" just means "replace each and every unit with the totality of units". For integers, that "unit" is 1. For strings, that "unit" is 1 character. You can literally square anything - numbers, strings, trees, salamis…. - as long as you also have a definition of "unit" that's applicable to the context.

@Renaud : If you want an example, run this awk code awk 'BEGIN { str = "Renaud"; gsub(/./, str, str); print str }' ::::: which prints out RenaudRenaudRenaudRenaudRenaudRenaud. That's what I call "string squaring". The input is 6 characters long, and the output is 6 copies of the input. But it grows REALLY fast. Run gsub(/./, str, str) just one more time and the output is 1,296 bytes long, comprised of 216 consecutive copies of your name. If you want strict squaring instead, then do gsub(orig_str, str, str) for all subsequent rounds.

Starter round of gsub(/./, str, str) once plus 3 rounds of gsub(orig_str, str, str) results in 1,679,616 copies of your name. 1679616 := 6^8 := 6^2^3, exactly equivalent to squaring it 3 times numerically if it were a number instead of a string. Standard approach of binary doubling for string repeats would take 21 rounds of the loop to reach the same figure.

for posix, you need newline after any label (since : cannot be followed by semicolon) and \n on rhs of s gives unspecified behaviour; you need an escaped literal newline - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/sed.html

@jhnc Right, thanks. I'm always a bit too optimistic about POSIX. I modified my answer.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/"(.*)"/\1/
        h
        s/./x/g
        s/(.*)\1/\n\1/
        G
        :a;s/\nx(.*)\n(.)/\n\1\2\n/;ta
        s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/"\1" "\2"/g
        H
        g;
        s/(.*)\n/"\1"\t-> /' file

First remove the input strings double quotes.
Make a copy of the original string.
Replace all original characters by x's.
Halve the template string and prepend a newline for scaffolding.
Append the original string.
Partition the original string using the halved template string.
Prepare the split strings.
Prepend the original string and present it in the pattern space.
Re-quote the original string and separate the  result by a tab and -> .
N.B. Best results are seen by setting tabs -16 before running sed.

Regex doesn't support the idea of a back reference for a variable quantifier, which if it did would allow you to do something like (.(*))(.{\2}).
However, you can capture each half as group 1 and 2, but you must cater for each length explicitly (this caters for an input up to 10 characters):
(.+)(?:(?<=^.)(?=.$)|(?<=^..)(?=..$)|(?<=^...)(?=...$)|(?<=^....)(?=....$)|(?<=^.....)(?=.....$))(.+)

See live demo.
Follow the pattern to support greater lengths.
This works by using an alternation in the middle of every equal length look behind to start and look ahead to end up to the longest supported length.

you should specify what regex flavor you are using (ruby) in the text of your answer, especially since you're using a different flavor than was asked for in the question. this also uses basically the same strategy as was used in the original question, except only to up to 10 instead of up to 1998; I was more asking for alternate approaches like what @bobble_bubble provided in the comments of the original question.
